# How to write client and server with TLS encryption in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, encryption, tcp

I am relatively new to Qt and have no experience in network programming. I am trying to write a minimal TCP-client-server connection with TLS encryption in Qt using the QSslSocket class. So far I established a connection between server and client both running on localhost without encryption. For TLS encryption I found this example on gitHub: https://github.com/GuiTeK/Qt-SslServer
and followed carefully the given instructions (including the OpenSSL installation). Nevertheless I can not establish a connection between client and server (even if I set timeout to -1). The error messages for the server and client are depicted below.
Can anybody help me with that ? If someone has complete code examples in Qt for client and server which exchange data via TCP using encryption SSL encryption I would highly appreciate. I am working with QtCreator running Qt 5.5.0 MSVC2013 64 bit.

Comment: "The error messages for the server and client are depicted below.” Where?

Comment: sorry somehow the upload of the pics failed

Answer (score 2):

Launch Qt Creator. On Welcome screen hit "Examples" button.  Then at search box write "ssl". You will see several fully working Qt examples for ssl clients and servers. This is the good place for start. Also read [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ssl.html) link.